# ejabberd server with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ejabberd, instant-messaging

We are developing a web application and we want to add chatting facility in our site. We are working on ruby on rails and found the xmpp4r gem that deals to create, update, delete users in ejabberd server and we wanted that user will get logged in into Ejabberd server once it logged in into our website and can send messages to others.  I went through xmpp4r documentation but unable to make it yet, how to do that all. Can somebody provide me a documentation for that and an example with ruby on rails? I have already configured ejabberd server.

Comment: it's better if you post the specific error your having. It seems like you're on the right track if you're running Ejabberd on a separate server and communicating with it using a Ruby gem. It seems like xmpp4r is badly documented. Maybe try `blather` instead.

Comment: **Thanks, @Max for your precious time and suggestion**, Currently, I'm running ejabberd on my machine(Ubuntu 14.04) only not in separate server, I want to be user get created to ejabberd server once User Sign up in our website and once user login into our site, User gets online into ejabberd server so that User able to chat with others. I am trying to do all scenario with ruby on rails (using xmpp4r gem) but **not able to even start with xmpp4r**.

Comment: This is all my scenario I wanted to do on my website. Help me for this and suggestions are welcome...And @Max, I will look into blather also, That might help. If possible, Please send example also I will very Thankful to you.

Comment: You can share reference also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, this is not how you build a chat system for a website using XMPP.

The most common approach is as follow:

- Create a Web XMPP client in Javascript.
- Making sure the user database is shared between your Rails app and ejabberd (or use ReST authentication module from ejabberd to Rails app).

If you use Rails to connect to ejabberd as a proxy, you will end up in a hell trying to manage the "reactor" to runs many XMPP clients inside your Rails web application. You are not supposed to run long running "processes" into Rails. It is not designed for that (and you will get memory, scalability and responsiveness issues).

Comment: ** Thanks @Mickael** It sound like Strophe js library. Is this one better than xmpp4r gem of ruby on rails?

Comment: Strophe is good indeed. The question is not if the lib is better than xmpp4r. The thing is that the whole design of the solution is better. With xmpp4r, you would be running many clients on the server. With Strophe the XMPP client runs on the browser and thus on the user client.

Comment: **Thanks @Michael** Last doubt....Is converse.js is another client for xmpp? what about strophe vs converse.js? And one doubt, can we do all the things that I have mentioned in my question with converse.js?

Comment: converse.js is an XMPP client. strophe is an XMPP library that can be used to write your own XMPP client.